# Is there a better way to concatenate continuous string elements in Python?

Tags: python, concatenation

***Problem Context***

I am trying to create a chat log dataset from Whatsapp chats. Let me just provide the context of what problem I am trying to solve. Assume message to be `M` and response to be `R`. The natural way in which chats happen is not always alternate, for e.g. chats tend to happen like this

`[ M, M, M, R, R, M, M, R, R, M ... and so on]`

I am trying to concatenate continuously occurring strings of M's and R's.
for the above example, I desire an output like this

***Desired Output***

> `[ "M M M", "R R", "M M" , "R R", "M ... and so on ]`

***An Example of Realistic Data:***

> ```
> Input --> ["M: Hi", "M: How are you?", "R: Heyy", "R: Im cool", "R: Wbu?"] (length=5)
>
> Output --> ["M: Hi M: How are you?", "R: Heyy R: Im cool R: Wbu?"] (length = 2)
> ```

Is there a **fast and more efficient** way of doing this?
I have already read [this Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489933/how-to-break-conversation-data-into-pairs-of-context-response) to solve this problem. But, I didn't find a solution there.

***So far, this is what I have tried***.

```
final= []
temp = ''
change = 0
for i,ele in enumerate(chats):
    if i>0:
        prev = chats[i-1][0]
        current = ele[0]

        if current == prev:
            continuous_string += chats[i-1]  
            continue
        else:
            continuous_string += chats[i-1]
            final.append(temp)
            temp = ''
```

***Explanation of my code:*** I have `chats` list in which the starting character of every message is 'M' and starting character of every response is 'R'. I keep track of `prev` value and `current` value in the list, and when there is a change (A transition from M -> R or R -> M), I append everything collected in the `continuous_string` to `final` list.

***Again, my question is:*** Is there a shortcut in Python or a function to do the same thing effectively in less number of lines?

Comment: Why are you doing `+ '. '` if there is no `.` in the desired output?

Comment: Ahh! Those are just messages which I want to concatenate with ". ". For the sake of the problem, their presence is irrelevant. Thanks for pointing out. I will make an edit! @Sanya

Comment: Please add some realistic sample data to your question so that people will stop posting useless answers that only work with the letters "M" and "R".

Comment: @TrebuchetMS Yes sir. Please look at the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the function `groupby()`:

```
from itertools import groupby

l = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B']

[' '.join(g) for _, g in groupby(l)]
# ['A A', 'B B']
```

To group data from your example you need to add a key to the the `groupby()` function:

```
l = ["M: Hi", "M: How are you?", "R: Heyy", "R: Im cool", "R: Wbu?"]

[' '.join(g) for _, g in groupby(l, key=lambda x: x[0])]
# ['M: Hi M: How are you?', 'R: Heyy R: Im cool R: Wbu?']
```

As @TrebuchetMS mentioned in the comments the key `lambda x: x.split(':')[0]` might be more reliable. It depends on your data.

Comment: I have edited the question a bit. Can you just show how those changes, please?

Comment: @Satya I added the solution for your realistic data.

Comment: Maybe `x.partition(':')[0]` or `x.split(':')[0]` in the lambda might be more reliable for data where the first letter is the same for different users. E.g. `["Megan: .", "Max: ."]`.

Comment: @MykolaZotko sorry I'm troubling you but can you give a brief explanation of how groupby works? Even a link which could explain it properly would be alright.

Comment: @Satya You get an iterator, which reterns consecutive keys and groups. Like a `dict`, where values  are groups. For `groupby(‘abbbcc’)` you get an iteraretor which looks like `{‘a’: [‘a’], ‘b’: [‘b’, ‘b’, ‘b’], ‘c’: [‘c’, ‘c’]}` (lists from previous example in a gropby abject are iterators).

Answer (score 2):

## Algorithm

- Initialize a temporary item. This will help determine if the speaker has changed
- For each item

  - Extract the speaker
  - If it's the same, append to the text of the last item of the array
  - Else append a new item in the list containing the speaker and text

## Implementation

```
def parse(x):
    parts = x.split(':')
    return parts[0], ' '.join(parts[1:]).strip()


def compress(l):
    ans = []
    prev = ''
    for x in l:
        curr, text = parse(x)
        if curr != prev:
            prev = curr
            ans.append(x)
        else:
            ans[len(ans) - 1] += f' {text}'
    return ans
```

## Character names

```
IN:  ["M: Hi", "M: How are you?", "R: Heyy", "R: Im cool", "R: Wbu?"]
OUT: ['M: Hi How are you?', 'R: Heyy Im cool Wbu?']
```

## String names

```
IN:  ["Mike: Hi", "Mike How are you?", "Mary: Heyy", "Mary: Im cool", "Mary: Wbu?"]
OUT: ['Mike: Hi How are you?', 'Mary: Heyy Im cool Wbu?']
```